# Calculating $\hom(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z})$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I am working on some homework and I am trying to compute $\hom(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z})$. I found a guide that said it would be the set $\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:np=0\}$. But the only element in $\mathbb{Z}$ that fullfill that would be $0$, is that correct? Or is the list help wrong as it seems a bit off and like it should be more.

Comment: Is $\Bbb{Z}_p$ the group of $p$-adic integers or the cyclic group of order $p$?

Comment: Perhaps the guide was identifying such homomorphisms by their action on the element of $\mathbf{Z}_{p}$ represented by $1$?  Every group homomorphism from $\mathbf{Z}_{p}$ to $\mathbf{Z}$ sends $0$ to $0$, but you have a choice in where it sends $1$.  The action of the homomorphism is then completely determined by this choice, since $\mathbf{Z}_{p}$ is cyclic and generated by $1$.

Comment: I never deal with adic numbers so I forget they exist but yes, I mean $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f \in \operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb{Z}_p , \Bbb{Z})$. Then by the first isomorphism theorem, $\Bbb{Z}_p / \ker f$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$. Recall that nontrivial subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}$ are infinite cyclic. But $\Bbb{Z}_p$ has no infinite quotients, so necessarily $\Bbb{Z}_p / \ker f$ is trivial! This implies that $\ker f = \Bbb{Z}_p$, i. e. $f=0$.

Comment: Damn I hate when such easy stuff just goes by without one noticing or thinking. My gut has failed me again! Thank you for this response, it made it clearer.

Comment: NOTE: this proof is valid whenever $\Bbb{Z}_p$ denotes a group with no infinite quotients. In particular it holds for finite groups, for $p$-adic integers, and for any profinite group as well.

Comment: Of course, I understood that, thank you again.

Comment: @Crostul I'm inclined to think that $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p/\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite. So, no, the argument won't work for the $p$-adic integers or profinite groups in general (where quotients with respect to *open* subgroups are finite). What can be used in the case of $p$-adic integers is that it's an indecomposable group; a nontrivial homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}$ would have a projective image.

Comment: @egreg You are right!